# iOS app beta TestFlight App Analytics

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, analytics, testflight, beta

My iOS app has been approved for beta testing. Can there be app analytics on the beta usage? I don't see the app listed on iTunes Connect App Analytics. Am I missing something? Is app analytics only for released(App Store) apps?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. What was your verdict here?

Comment: I gave up on this one.

Comment: Did you find another solution to get analytics while in TestFlight?

Comment: Well I guess you can rely on third party analytics. There's many out there.